# sql query to get friends based on email

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have sample data that looks like this

```
| users                              |
| user_id | email                    |
|---------|--------------------------|
| 1       | test@example.com |
| 2       | Kanchhi@example.com      |
| 3       | modi@example.com         |
| 4       | andy@example.com         |
| 5       | maya@example.com         |
| 6       | jetli@example.com        |
| 7       | john@example.com         |

| user_relations                                                          |
| user_relation_id | requestor_user_id | receiver_user_id | friend_status |
|------------------|-------------------|------------------|---------------|
| 1                | 2                 | 4                | 1             |
| 2                | 2                 | 6                | 1             |
| 3                | 2                 | 7                | 1             |
| 4                | 5                 | 2                | NULL          |
| 5                | 5                 | 7                | NULL          |
| 6                | 7                 | 2                | NULL          |
| 7                | 7                 | 4                | 1             |
| 8                | 7                 | 5                | 1             |
| 9                | 7                 | 6                | 1             |
| 10               | 4                 | 2                | 1             |
| 11               | 4                 | 3                | 1             |
| 12               | 4                 | 5                | 1             |
| 13               | 4                 | 6                | 1             |
| 14               | 4                 | 7                | 1             |
```

If input is these two emails:

```
Kanchhi@example.com, john@example.com
```

Then my expected expected output is this (order does not matter):

```
andy@example.com
jetli@example.com
```

In the above example, the friends of user id 2 is user ids (4, 6, 7) and friend of user id 7 is user ids (2, 4, 5, 6). So the mutual friend of user id 2 and 7 is **4 and 6**. I need email address of mutual user id.

Another example input is:

```
andy@example.com, john@example.com
```

Then expected output is this:

```
jetli@example.com
Kanchhi@example.com
maya@example.com`
```

In the above example, friend of user id 4 is (2, 6, 5, 3, 2) and friend of user id 7 is (6, 5, 2, 4). So mutual friend user id will be **2, 6, 5**. I need email address of these user id in output.

**Query 1- I tried but got wrong result**:

```
SELECT  u.email 
       FROM user_relations r 
        LEFT JOIN users u   ON r.requestor_user_id = u.user_id
        LEFT JOIN users z   ON r.receiver_user_id = z.user_id
       where u.email in ('Kanchhi@example.com','john@example.com') or 
       z.email in ('Kanchhi@example.com','john@example.com') 
       and r.friend_status = 1 
       group by u.email 
      having count(u.email ) > 1
```

**Results- but not correc**:

```
| email               |
|---------------------|
| andy@example.com    |
| john@example.com    |
| Kanchhi@example.com |
```

How to get this?

Comment: sqlfiddle is great, but seems to be a bit tired today. Can't you add sample table data and the expected result as formatted text as well?

Comment: Remember that AND goes before OR. Perhaps you should try `where (u.email in ('Kanchhi@example.com','john@example.com') or 
       z.email in ('Kanchhi@example.com','john@example.com'))
       and r.friend_status = 1 `?

Comment: @jarlh enjoy. SQLFiddle is getting more and more tired days after days, I tend to prefer dbfiddle for that reason

Comment: Why is john a frind of himself in your example?

Comment: @SalmanA that's not OP's expected output, it's output of his current query. The expected is in the top of OP post.

Comment: @SalmanA `The friend of user id 2 is user ids (4,6,7) and friend of user id 7 is user ids(2,4,5,6) so the mutual friend of user id 2 & 7 is (4 and 6 ) << this is my expected output but i need email address of mutual userId(4,6)`

Comment: @AshutoshSingh put your previous commentary in your ask   please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start from the user, then join the relations.

Then group on the receiver & requestor that are different from the user.

```
SELECT 
case when u.user_id = r.receiver_user_id then requestor.email else receiver.email end as friend_email
FROM users u
JOIN user_relations r 
  ON (r.requestor_user_id = u.user_id OR r.receiver_user_id = u.user_id)
 AND r.friend_status = 1 
LEFT JOIN users requestor ON requestor.user_id = r.requestor_user_id
LEFT JOIN users receiver ON receiver.user_id = r.receiver_user_id
WHERE u.email in ('Kanchhi@example.com','john@example.com') 
GROUP BY friend_email
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT u.user_id) > 1
```

**Result:**

```
friend_email
----------------
andy@example.com 
jetli@example.com
```

Comment: On same data , If i am pass  another  2 input like `'andy@example.com','john@example.com'`  then i am expectinging three results but your query is giving 5 results along with the input . i need only 3 correct output.....  Expected output for this case `jetli@example.com, Kanchhi@example.com  , maya@example.com`  , When input is ``'andy@example.com','john@example.com'``

Comment: @AshutoshSingh Ok, I overlooked that part about "Mutual friends". I changed the HAVING clause. Looks fine now.

Comment: thats working,Can you help me write Another seperate sql query to fetch follower list! Here, i want to find out emails who are followers of that email...  in same data if i pass, email `maya@example.com` then expected output should be `john@example.com, andy@example.com`  , i tried like as shown in screenshot but 0 result https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWb2g.jpg

Comment: @AshutoshSingh  Just by looking at that SQL.  Note that in SQL the AND's are evaluated before the OR's.  So `x OR y AND z` is evaluated as `x OR (y AND z)`. That's why when you mix OR's and AND's that you better add the parentesis. To avoid logical misunderstandings.  For example to group the OR's together.  Which I also did in this answer btw.

Comment: @AshutoshSingh, why can't you respect the rules and only ask one question at the time and not try to sneak in extra questions in the comments section?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson That is related question to the same question i asked. Instead of asking a new question, i have asked in the same question, i think its good! i have not spam the Stackoverflow by creating new similar question! Don't you think so?

Comment: @AshutoshSingh No I don't think so. The question you posted and the answers might be helpful to others as well so it's important to keep it as simple and clean as possible and only have one question at a time so others can read it without being confused. It's better to "spam" actually in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

The crux of the problem is building a list of users that are friends of Kanchi and John or have them as friends. Then count those users that appear in the list twice:

```
-- SELECT email FROM users WHERE userid IN (
SELECT friendid
FROM (
    SELECT requestor_user_id AS userid, receiver_user_id AS friendid
    FROM user_relations
    WHERE friend_status = 1 AND requestor_user_id IN (
        SELECT user_id
        FROM users
        WHERE email IN ('Kanchhi@example.com','john@example.com')
    )

    UNION ALL

    SELECT receiver_user_id, requestor_user_id
    FROM user_relations
    WHERE friend_status = 1 AND receiver_user_id IN (
        SELECT user_id
        FROM users
        WHERE email IN ('Kanchhi@example.com','john@example.com')
    )
) AS X
GROUP BY friendid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT userid) = 2
```

Matching the results with users is trivial. For your sample input the result is:

```
4    Andy     andy@example.com     ashutosh    2019-01-11 13:34:05
6    jetli    jetli@example.com    ashutosh    2019-01-11 13:34:05
```

Comment: Why should I? What about this one?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this and use index in join coulmn for performance

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.email
FROM
(
    SELECT r.receiver_user_id AS id, u.email
    FROM user_relations r 
    INNER JOIN users u
    ON r.requestor_user_id = u.user_id 
    WHERE r.friend_status = 1 AND u.email = 'Kanchhi@example.com'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT r.requestor_user_id AS id, u.email
    FROM user_relations r 
    INNER JOIN users u
    ON r.receiver_user_id = u.user_id 
    WHERE r.friend_status = 1 AND u.email = 'Kanchhi@example.com'
) k
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT r.receiver_user_id AS id, u.email
    FROM user_relations r 
    INNER JOIN users u
    ON r.requestor_user_id = u.user_id 
    WHERE r.friend_status = 1 AND u.email = 'john@example.com'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT r.requestor_user_id AS id, u.email
    FROM user_relations r 
    INNER JOIN users u
    ON r.receiver_user_id = u.user_id 
    WHERE r.friend_status = 1 AND u.email = 'john@example.com'
) j
ON k.id = j.id
INNER JOIN users u 
ON k.id = u.user_id 
AND u.email NOT IN ('Kanchhi@example.com','john@example.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT usu.email from users usu where usu.user_id in (
select          r.receiver_user_id
from sov.user_relations r 
where r.requestor_user_id in (
    SELECT  u.user_id from users u where u.email in ('Kanchhi@example.com','john@example.com') 
     )
and r.friend_status = 1      
group by r.receiver_user_id
having count(r.receiver_user_id)  > 1
);
```

Answer (score 0):

> you can create extra function like below code

```
BEGIN
DECLARE limitCount INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE res INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE temp TEXT;
SET limitCount = 1 + LENGTH(inputList) - LENGTH(REPLACE(inputList, ',',''));
simple_loop:LOOP
SET counter = counter + 1;
SET temp = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(inputList,',',counter),',',-1);
SET res = FIND_IN_SET(temp,targetList);
IF res > 0 THEN LEAVE simple_loop; END IF;
IF counter = limitCount THEN LEAVE simple_loop; END IF;
END LOOP simple_loop;
RETURN res;
END
```

> AND USE THIS FUNCTION LIKE THIS

```
find_in_set_extra('Kanchhi@example.com, john@example.com','john@example.com') OR WHAT EVER YOUR INPUTS AND OUTPUTS.
```